# Structuring associations Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

This is probably a fairly straight forward answer that I feel like I should know, but occasionally I run across something like this that stumps me.

I'm working on a rails app that requires me to essentially create a leasing system for rentals.

I've got a user, a building, a lease and an unit.  The way I've got it structured right now is:

```
class Buildings < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :units
    has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :buildings
   has_many :units, through :lease      
end

class Lease < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :unit
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :building
    belongs_to :user 

    has_one :lease
end
```

I'm running into syntax errors and association errors and the documentation is as clear as mud.  Perhaps someone can help me to properly structure these associations.

Comment: Which documentation did you follow?

Comment: guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your syntax error is on the User class

Change

```
 has_many :units, through :lease
```

to

```
has_many :unit, through: :lease
```

or

```
 has_many :units, :through => :lease
```

Comment: Your answer needs review? Await the documentation from OP!